# How do I normalize and simplify (A ^ B) --> !B v C v !(A v C)

Tags: logic, logical-operators

How do I normalize and simplify `(A ^ B) --> !B v C v !(A v C)`

I've normalized the expression using the rule that `(A->B) = !A` or `B`. But I'm not sure how to simplify it. I've ended up with the answer `!A v !B v C`.

Is this correct and if not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where does the `C` comes in, you will have t provide more context.

Comment: We don't need to know what A, B, or C is in the expression to simplify it.  @Alex - you would have probably had more luck in the Mathematics exchange. Programmers don't often get this kind of pure logic / math question. I had to dust off the ol' math degree to muster up how to solve this one...

Comment: @Jake: but the question is tagged with [tag:prolog], so usually that means a person is looking for a program in Prolog (don't you think). So at least it is tagged the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the same answer as you.

```
1. (A ^ B) => !B V C V !(A v C)
2. (A ^ B) => !B V C V (!A ^ !C)
3. (A ^ B) => !B V (C V (!A ^ !C))  //(C V (!A ^ !C)) => C V !A
4. (A ^ B) => !B V (C V !A)
5. (A ^ B) => !A V !B V C
6. !(A ^ B) V (!A V !B V C)
7. (!A V !B) V (!A V !B V C)
8. !A V !B V C
```

Suggestion...Do a truth table for the expression in step 1 and see if it matches the truth table for the expression in step 8. That will verify that our logic is correct. As far as simplification goes, step 8 is as far as it can go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!